# Microsoft Project 2013 Custom Report Not Respecting Task Filter

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I've recently made the move to Project 2013 Standard (15.0.4727.1001) and seem to be having problems using even simple filters I've created within custom reports.  For example, I wanted to create a simple "show all tasks which are past their finish date" report.  Starting simple, I created a filter with one criterion:

```
"<%Complete> <is not equal to> <100%>"
```

The report returns only a handful of tasks (mostly summary tasks, if that's any clue) - but many fewer than meet this criterion. This occurs regardless of the Outline Level I select.

This seems so straight-forward I must be missing something - or is this functionality just that weak?

**Update:** It appears that some of the predefined filters aren't being respected, either. For example, my report only shows one task with the "In Progress" filter applied and only a handful when the "Incomplete Tasks" filter is applied - both clearly wrong.

Comment: What report are you attempting to run and filter?

Comment: I'm creating my own custom report with a single table - it's so simple, I'm beginning to wonder whether there is a bug in play.

Comment: That said, it appears that some of the "standard" reports seem to be acting strangely as well with filters applied. For example, on the standard "project overview" dashboard the "past due" table doesn't display any tasks (and there are certainly overdue tasks) - but when I change the filter to from "Past Due" to "All Tasks" I get the listing I would expect. Hmmm...

Comment: The Late Tasks filter uses the Status field, which relies upon the Status date.  Is your status date set?  Check Project Information.

Comment: As far as tracking down the issue - apply the filter in a Gantt chart view - does it work as expected?

Comment: I did not have a Status Date set, so I did - but the "project overview" late tasks table still did not show any tasks as late.  As I went to try the filter on the Gantt Chart view, I expanded all subtasks in the plan and, viola, the report then populated the dashboard and my custom reports correctly. Perhaps I missed something - but does the level of roll-up used in the Gantt Chart view determine which tasks are "visible" within reports?  That would seem a strange way to link two conceptually-independent views into a project's data. If this is true, please post as an "answer" & I'll check it.

Comment: It does.  In earlier versions of Project you could see this easily if you collapsed Tasks in the Task Usage view and then tried to print the Cash Flow report.  I'd go ahead and copy your comment as the answer.  You're the one who found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some continued experimentation, I determined that the degree to which tasks are rolled-up in the Gantt Chart view determines which tasks are "visible" within reports.  To solve my problem, I simply expanded all of the subtasks in the plan and the reports then populated correctly. While this seems like a strange way for Microsoft to have designed reporting, this is apparently the PAD behavior.  I've searched for a reference stating such but cannot find one - if anyone does, please post it as a comment.